# having trouble with mysql code keep getting error 1064

Tags: mysql

here is the code i have, i get an error with the SELECT *FROM judge;

```
CREATE VIEW judge_vw AS(

  SELECT *FROM judge;
  WHERE suburb='adelaide';
  order by 'judge_id';`enter code here`
  with check option;

insert into judge_vw values(',judge_id 6','schofield','adelaide,')

update judge_vw set name='russell'where names='jones'

delete from judge_vw where judge_id=7;

drop view if exists judge_vw
);
```

Answer (score 0):

your sintax is wrong  leave just the last ; at the end of command and remove all the others
don't use quote for column name (eg:  judge_id), remve unuseful ( and  with chcek

```
CREATE VIEW judge_vw AS 
SELECT * FROM judge
WHERE suburb='adelaide'
ORDER BY judge_id;
```

you insert seems contain wrong comma

```
insert into judge_vw values('judge_id 6','schofield','adelaide');
```

Answer (score 0):

remove unnecessary semicolumn's

```
CREATE VIEW judge_vw AS
      SELECT *FROM judge
      WHERE suburb='adelaide'
      order by judge_id;


    insert into judge_vw values('judge_id 6','schofield','adelaide');

    update judge_vw set name='russell'where names='jones';

    delete from judge_vw where judge_id=7;

    drop view if exists judge_vw;
```